# PowerBi - Updating a report on the PowerBi Cloud

Tags: powerbi

This is a n00b question. I need to make some changes to a report that has been published on the PowerBi Cloud. I need to make some changes to a visual. After making the changes, I publish the report. It ends up creating a new report in the workspace. Is there a way to update the report with the changes from PowerBi Desktop? Or do I need to remove the old one and create a new report? I could find any documentation on this.

Comment: It should overwrite the old report unless you've changed the name of the file you're publishing.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the report is the same name and it is being published to the same workspace it will overwrite. This maintains the report's GUID (internal identifier) which is also used in the hyperlink to the report, so is handy to keep constant.

[image]

You can test this by publishing a report and opening it once published. Check this link and the report content. Change the report and publish again - it will ask you to overwrite. Once re-published, you can refresh and see the report link stays constant but the report is updated.